# Java string searching ignoring accents - part II

Tags: java, unicode

This question is a continuation of [Java string searching ignoring accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397804/java-string-searching-ignoring-accents).

The answer to the original question shows us how to remove the diacritics from strings. So, for instance, **köln** becomes **koln**. But **łódź** becomes **łodz** - note the [l with stroke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81).

My question is how can I remove the stroke as well, so that **łódź** becomes **lodz**?

Thanks.

Comment: You were given the wrong answer.  See my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, at least not trivially for all such letters. The letter `ł` is (except for appearance and its Unicode name) not linked to `l` at all (in Unicode at least; linguistically that's a different matter).

Your only option might be a conversion table for your use case you can fill with all the characters you need to convert.

Comment: **This answer is incorrect!!**  According to the current DUCET used by the Unicode Collation Algorithm, the primary collation strength for U+0142 `LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE` (that `ł` character) is identical to that of a normal `LATIN SMALL LETTER L`.  The correct answer is to compare strings using the Unicode Collation Algorithm but with the strength set to primary (level one) only. You will probably have to use ICU if you’re stuck with Java, because the Sun libraries do not correctly implement the UCA.

Comment: Admitted, I didn't look at what they actually want to do and took this question as »How can I create a new string where `ł` gets converted to `l`?« I guess that *would* be difficult using collation algorithm (barring enumeration of all possible strings). So I was mainly looking at decomposition. I can't delete until unaccept, though.

Comment: I want the unaccented string indeed.

Answer (score 1):

As tchrist suggested, I attempted to use ICU (V 50.1): it didn't recognize it as derived from L either.
The L with stroke seems to be a special case in Unicode. Look at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11369
They say in Unicode 4.0 it was not connected to L, while in Unicode 4.1 it is. I wonder if anyone tested the problem with a Unicode4.1-based Java library.