# Compromis between SQLite and MS SQL in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, offline

is there something between SQLite and MS SQL or MySQL in Android? I need for example to do accent independent search in SQLite, but i did not find good solutions...Maybe there is some library or something else. I also need to keep my database offline and the solution should work for API 7+.

Comment: Perhaps remove the accents before you search: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2397830/1898380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Android` does provide support for `SQLite` only as this DBMS is file based, which is useful because every application can potentially use one. In order to use `MySQL` your only option is to put it online, and then access it from the device via web services.