# Search that does not take accents into account

Tags: java, regex, flags, accent-sensitive

I'm doing a search engine that doesn't take capital letters, minuscules or accents into account. I've done this but the accents part doesn't work well for me.

```
@Override
public CResponse getAll(int page, int size, String name) {
    CResponse response = new CResponse();
    Page<CDocument> cDocument = Repository.findByBasicsNameRegexOrderById(
            Pattern.compile(name, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE),
            PageRequest.of(page, size));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe related? [Java string searching ignoring accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397804/java-string-searching-ignoring-accents)

Comment: I want to search for "Tom" and I want to return both "Tom" and "Tóm" and when I search for "Sám" I want to return both "Sam" and "Sám".