# How to set up collators strength and decomposition for sorting unicode string by first letter

Tags: java, unicode, collation

I have a list of unicode strings that I want to sort by first letter. The problem is that I don't know to set up java.text.Collator that it would treat similar letters as different.

This is what I get now:

- Rokiškis
- Šakiai
- **Salantai**
- Šeduva
- Šiauliai
- Šilalė
- **Skuodas**
- Tauragė
- Telšiai

This is what I want to get (word beginning with **Š** should always go after **S** not looking to second letter):

- Rokiškis
- **Salantai**
- **Skuodas**
- Šakiai
- Šeduva
- Šiauliai
- Šilalė
- Tauragė
- Telšiai

Comment: All Java strings are Unicode strings.

Comment: Doesn't ICU4J offer something to help with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java. Ignore accents when comparing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373213/java-ignore-accents-when-comparing-strings)

Answer (score 1):

We can create a class extends Collator and override the compare method there.

An example is here.

public class MyCollator extends Collator {

```
@Override
public int compare(String source, String target) {
    return source.compareTo(target);
}

@Override
public CollationKey getCollationKey(String source) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

Then we can use this newly added class to sort the String list, and it will display in a correct way.

**Collator collator = new MyCollator();**

**Collections.sort(list, collator);**

**My Test Result is as follows:**

- Rokiškis
- Salantai
- Skuodas
- Tauragė
- Telšiai
- Šakiai
- Šeduva
- Šiauliai
- Šilalė

Note, in the result, **Š** is displaying  after **T**, this is because **"Š".compareTo("T")>1** is equal to true.

I believe you can put some logic in compare method to make  **Š** displaying just after **S**, but before **T**.

The above code is complied and executed using JDK 1.5 version.

Use **Collections.sort(list)** directly; You will get the same result as I mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to write my own Collator rules, because according to docs Java 6 Collator supports locale of this language. So I want to know how solve this problem in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

So I tested all variants of Collators strength and decomposition and nothing changed. What I found that by my locale ("lt_LT") such sorting that was given was actually grammaticaly correct.