# Java string comparison - ignore letter accents and case

Tags: java, regex, string, unicode, utf

I am trying to look for a way to compare two Strings without taking into consideration their letter accents and case.

I am parsing a large document with many names in different languages and sometimes users forget to add the accents, are just lazy to add the accents to their names, or the fact that the same name in different languages is spelled with the same letters but without the accent.

So for example, `"COTE D'IVOIRE" = "Côte d'Ivoire"` will be true.

I know Java has a built in `.equalsIgnoreCase` but how do I compare accents while ignoring accents AND case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373213/java-ignore-accents-when-comparing-strings

Answer (score 0):

you could 1st strip out all the accents using a [Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190656/easy-way-to-remove-utf-8-accents-from-a-string)) and then compare ignoring case.

**EDIT** - or, as user @lbarros pointed out, a [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) would work even better

Comment: Actually I think the Normalizer class would work better as stated in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397804/java-string-searching-ignoring-accents since Collator is better for sorting and not equality comparison.

Comment: @Kingamere - comparison is a superset of equality, but either way one of those should work for you