# Is it not possible to access a scanner within a scanner in Java?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

Goal: I'm creating a program that would allow me to calculate the area of multiple types of figures. To do so, I want to use a scanner to read user input and assess if the String provided is equal to one of my figure names. If so, it would invoke a method from the figure class that has another scanner.

Error: It's giving me an input mismatch when I enter the figure's name to be redirected to another class' scanner. Here's the error ->

```
    Forneça qual figura dentre estas você deseja calcular a área de: circunferência, triângulo, retângulo, quadrado, trapézio, paralelogramo.
circulo
Forneça o raio do círculo:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at com.company.Circle.calculateCircleArea(Calculator.java:42)
    at com.company.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's the code:

```
    package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Forneça qual figura dentre estas você deseja calcular a área de: circunferência, triângulo, retângulo, quadrado, trapézio, paralelogramo.");
        String equals = scanner.nextLine();

        if (equals.toLowerCase().equals("círculo") || equals.toLowerCase().equals("circulo")) {
            scanner.close();
            Circle.calculateCircleArea();
        } else if(equals.toLowerCase().equals("quadrado")) {
            scanner.close();
            Square.calculateSquareArea();
        } else if(equals.toLowerCase().equals("trapézio") || equals.toLowerCase().equals("trapezio")) {
            scanner.close();
            Trapezium.calculateTrapeziumArea();
        } else if(equals.toLowerCase().equals("paralelogramo") || equals.toLowerCase().equals("paralelograma")) {
            scanner.close();
            Parallelogram.calculateParallelogramArea();
        } else if(equals.toLowerCase().equals("retângulo") || equals.toLowerCase().equals("retangulo")) {
            scanner.close();
            Rectangle.calculateRectangleArea();
        } else if(equals.toLowerCase().equals("triangulo") || equals.toLowerCase().equals("triângulo")) {
            scanner.close();
            Triangle.calculateTriangleArea();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Figura inválida. Veja se foi escrita de forma correta e execute o programa novamente.");
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}

class Circle {
    public static void calculateCircleArea() {
        Scanner circle = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Forneça o raio do círculo:");
        double radius = circle.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("A area do círculo é: " + (Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2)));

        circle.nextLine();
        circle.close();
    }
}

class Square {
    public static void calculateSquareArea() {
        Scanner square = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Forneça valor de um dos lados do quadrado:");
        double side = square.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("A area do quadrado é: " + Math.pow(side,2));

        square.nextLine();
        square.close();
    }
}

class Trapezium {
    public static void calculateTrapeziumArea() {
        Scanner trapezium = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Forneça o valor da menor base do seu trapézio:");
        double smallBase = trapezium.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Forneça o valor da maior base do seu trapézio:");
        double largeBase = trapezium.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Forneça o valor da altura do seu trapézio:");
        double height = trapezium.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("A area de seu trapézio é: " + (((smallBase + largeBase) * height)/2));

        trapezium.nextLine();
        trapezium.close();
    }
}


class Parallelogram {
    public static void calculateParallelogramArea() {
        Scanner parallelogram = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Forneça o valor da base do seu paralelogramo:");
        double base = parallelogram.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Forneça o valor da altura do seu paralelogramo:");
        double height = parallelogram.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("A area do seu paralelogramo é: " + base * height);

        parallelogram.close();
    }
}

class Rectangle {
    public static void calculateRectangleArea() {
        Scanner rectangle = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Forneça o valor do comprimento do seu retângulo:");
        double length = rectangle.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Forneça o valor da altura do seu retângulo:");
        double height = rectangle.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("A area do seu retângulo é: " + length * height);

        rectangle.close();
    }
}

class Triangle {
    public static void calculateTriangleArea() {
        Scanner triangle = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Forneça o valor da base de seu triângulo:");
        double base = triangle.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Forneça o valor da altura do seu triângulo:");
        double height = triangle.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("O valor da area do seu triângulo é:" + (height * base) / 2);

        triangle.close();
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate it so much if I could get some help. I'm still a beginner learning to program. It'd be largely appreciated!

EDIT: The non-essential parts of the code, aka the response and the questions are in Portuguese. For the error here's what it's saying -> Enter which of these figures' area you wish to calculate: circumference, triangle, circle, rectangle, trapezium, etc.
I enter: circle
It then leads to to the Circle class and asks: Enter the circle's radius ->
But before I can press anything the scanner's already closed and the error is in place.

Comment: Remove **all** of the `.close()` calls. When you close a `Scanner` on `System.in` you also close `System.in` (and you can't open it again).

Comment: Can't believe the solution was that simple. It worked, thank you. :)

Comment: No need to explain about the Portuguese.  We can all see what's going on.

Comment: You might want to look into using collator to ignore accents in string comparisons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40132590/360211